# Lock in multi-threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

```
class Port
{
    static readonly object locker = new object();
    List<Connection> listOfConnections = new List<Connection>

    public void MethodX()
    {
       Thread.Sleep(10000);
       lock(locker)
       {
           listOfConnections.RemoveAt(0);
       }
    }

    public void ReceiveFromSwitch()
    {
        lock(locker)
        {
           if(listOfConnections.Count == 0) listOfConnections.Add(new Connection());
           if(listOfConnections.Count == 1) MessageBox.Show("Whatever");

           new Thread(()=>MetohodX()).Start();
        }
    }
}
```

That's my code, two different threads call the method ReceiveFromSwitch(). My objective is to be given a messagebox "Whatever". One thread starts first. It steps into ReceiveFromSwitch, locks the resource and the second thread is waiting for the resource to be released. A connection on the list is added, it steps into MethodX() and release the method ReceiveFromSwitch for a thread in the queue. The second one steps into the method. The count equals 1, so it shows message.

It doesn't work. It gives two messages "Whatever". How can i fix it?

Comment: Silly question but are the two threads calling the method on the same instance of `Port`? Because the list is not static.

Comment: Yes. it is the same instance.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

You forgot an else.

```
if(listOfConnections.Count == 0) listOfConnections.Add(new Connection());
else if(listOfConnections.Count == 1) MessageBox.Show("Whatever");

//or better yet
if (listOfConnections.Any())
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("Whatever");
}
else
{
    listOfConnections.Add(new Connection());
}
```

What's happening is the first thread enters and adds a connection to the list, and then immediately shows the message because the `Count` is now 1.
The second thread enters, and as expected, shows the second message.

There is another problem with your code. The second thread will also trigger `MethodX`, and when it executes after 10 seconds, it will try to remove index 0 from an already empty list, causing an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: Thanks, however it was just an example based on much longer code. The solution was deeper. Locker was doing great, but I was so confused that I suspected my incompetence was a reason of not working properly.